# jQuery - simple input validation - "empty" and "not empty"

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

I have an input that I want to validate:

```
<input type="text" id="input" />
```

And here's the JS:

```
        jQuery("#input").live('change', function() {

            if("#input:not(:empty)") {
                alert('not empty');
            }   

            else if("#input:empty") {
                alert('empty'); 
            }
        });
```

Even when the "#input" is empty there's no way of displaying alert with "empty" message. So, basically, no matter what I do, only the first statement is true and the second is false, always.

What's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if inputs are empty using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854556/check-if-inputs-are-empty-using-jquery)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**[JQuery's :empty selector](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)** selects all elements on the page that are empty in the sense that **they have no child elements, including text nodes**, not all inputs that have no text in them.

**[Jquery: How to check if an input element has not been filled in.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854556/how-to-check-if-inputs-are-empty-with-jquery)**

Here's the code stolen from the above thread:

```
$('#apply-form input').blur(function()          //whenever you click off an input element
{                   
    if( !$(this).val() ) {                      //if it is blank. 
         alert('empty');    
    }
});
```

This works because an empty string in JavaScript is a 'falsy value', which basically means if you try to use it as a boolean value it will always evaluate to `false`. If you want, you can change the conditional to `$(this).val() === ''` for added clarity. :D

Answer (score 6):

You could do this

```
$("#input").blur(function(){
    if($(this).val() == ''){
        alert('empty'); 
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/Y5P9k/1/

When the input has lost `focus` that is `.blur()`, then check the value of the `#input`.

If it is empty `== ''` then trigger the alert.

Answer (score 2):

```
    jQuery("#input").live('change', function() {
        // since we check more than once against the value, place it in a var.
        var inputvalue = $("#input").attr("value");

        // if it's value **IS NOT** ""
        if(inputvalue !== "") {
            jQuery(this).css('outline', 'solid 1px red'); 
        }   

        // else if it's value **IS** ""
        else if(inputvalue === "") {
            alert('empty'); 
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a simpler way to do this, just:

```
if ($("#input").is(':empty')) {
console.log('empty');
} else {
console.log('not empty');
}
```

src: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-an-html-element-is-empty-using-jquery/

Comment: Actually, coming from now, jQuery 3.5.1, this is not a valid answer.
As answered in the accepted answer :empty checks for if the input has children, which is not what the asker wanted.

To validate an input using :empty, at least nowadays with :empty does not work, it's wrong.

(10 years later than the original answer. But the answer is still here, and upvoted also... Please remove it or update it? For example if it was valid in older versions)