# trim and check if empty input

Tags: jquery, validation

```
if(!$.trim($('.xlarge').value).length) {
    return false;
}
```

And the HTML is:

```
<input class="xlarge" name="name">
```

I checked on my console if the syntax is right, it is right, but even  if the value is not empty it still doesn't submit the form. What's wrong?

Comment: `$('.xlarge').value` will be `undefined` as `$('.xlarge')` is a jQuery object and does not have a `value` property. You either want to access the DOM element `$('.xlarge')[0].value` or use the `.val()` function: `$('.xlarge').val()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to check length just use :

```
if(!$.trim($('.xlarge').val())) {
     return false;
}
```

val() returns the value of the input - [docs for val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Discussed here [Check if inputs are empty using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854556/how-to-check-if-inputs-are-empty-with-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

```
if($.trim($('.xlarge').val()) == "") {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
$('.xlarge').value
```

You should use:

```
$('.xlarge').val()
```

`.val()` is the jQuery function which will return the `value` of the first element in the set of matched elements. Here's a link to the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/val/.