# jQuery input validator and asp:CustomValidator

Tags: jquery

I am creating input fields with jquery

```
var randomNum = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 99999);        
    $("<p class='" + randomNum + "'>First name: <input type='text'  name='kontaktFormaIme" + randomNum + "' class='required' id='kontaktFormaIme" + randomNum + "' maxlength='50' /></p>").appendTo(".kontakt");
    $("<p class='" + randomNum + "'>Last NameIme: <input type='text'  name='kontaktFormaPrezime" + randomNum + "' class='required' id='kontaktFormaPrezime" + randomNum + "'  /></p>").appendTo(".kontakt");
```

with this I can creat as many as I want

What is easy way to check for example every  with ID that starts with "kontaktFormaIme" or have class 'required'

[This is good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854556/how-to-check-if-inputs-are-empty-with-jquery)

But I don' know how to make general checker, I have tried something like this but it is not working

```
function ValidateKontakt(source, args) {
    var isFormValid = true;
    $(".required input").each(function () {
        if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0) {                
            $(this).addClass("highlight");
            isFormValid = false;
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass("highlight");
        }
    });
    args.IsValid = isFormValid;
}
```

Comment: what does you mean by not working? any error check in Error log

Comment: looks like $(".required input") wasn't good selector, but your sugestion worked like charm

Comment: good! you can also vote up ;)

Comment: I can't :( I need 15 points to do that

Comment: no worries you can do it any time wherever you can..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can select the HTML element using jQuery startsWith selector..

```
$("input[id^='kontaktFormaIme']")
```

I may be wrong with quotes. please take care of it...