# call up form submit event if fields are filled

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, bind, onbeforeunload

I have a form in sidebar on few pages of my website

```
<form id="test1" name="test1">
 <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
 <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" />

 <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
 <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" />

 <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
 <textarea name="comment" id="comment"><textarea/>

 <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

My requirement is something odd. If someone has filled up the form (even partially) and then leaving current page (by going to some other page, or closing browser tab/ window), then form should be submitted.

I am putting following jQuery code to achieve following:

```
<script>
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
    $('form').each(function(index) {
    var filled = false;
    $(this).find("input").each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != "") {
            filled = true;
        }
    });
    if (filled) { this.submit(); }
});
return confirm('test');
});
```

Above code is not working properly, form is not getting submitted. Help please.

Answer (score 0):

Variable filled is declared inside $(form).each and used outside of it

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you should use $(this) instead of this on submitting.
2. Maybe you should also check on the value comparison (see e.g. [Check if inputs are empty using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854556/check-if-inputs-are-empty-using-jquery))

@amtanay: as far as I can see, the nesting is correct...

New Code (untested):

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
  $('form').each(function(index) {
    var filled = false;
    $(this).find("input").each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() != "") {
        filled = true;
      }
    });
    if (filled) { $(this).submit(); }
  });
  return confirm('test');
});
```

You could also think about submitting the form as soon as you find a non-empty field. There is no need to check on all the fields, if the form should be submitted even if it is only partially filled up.