# How to check if the any of my textbox is empty or not in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if inputs are empty using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854556/check-if-inputs-are-empty-using-jquery)

I have form and textboxes, how will I determine if any of these textboxes is empty using javascript if else statement once a form button is clicked.

```
function checking() {
    var textBox = $('input:text').value;
    if (textBox == "") {
        $("#error").show('slow');
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854556/check-if-inputs-are-empty-using-jquery

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By using jQuery selectors for selecting the elements, you have a jQuery object and you should use `val()` method for getting/setting value of input elements.

Also note that `:text` selector is *deprecated* and it would be better to trim the text for removing whitespace characters. you can use `$.trim` utility function.

```
function checking() {
    var textBox =  $.trim( $('input[type=text]').val() )
    if (textBox == "") {
        $("#error").show('slow');
    }
}
```

If you want to use `value` property you should first convert the jQuery object to a raw DOM object. You can use `[index]` or `get` method.

```
 var textBox = $('input[type=text]')[0].value;
```

If you have multiple inputs you should loop through them.

```
function checking() {
    var empty = 0;
    $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
       if (this.value == "") {
           empty++;
           $("#error").show('slow');
       } 
    })
   alert(empty + ' empty input(s)')
}
```

Comment: Hi! This didnt work as well. I have 6 textboxes and two of these textboxes do have values, does it affect the condition? What Im trying to do is once user click the submit button and any of the remaining textboxes is empty the error warning will show. Thanks.

Comment: Hi! No good, i think I dont have to do looping. Actually I have long solution --> 

`function checking() 
 {
  if(document.getElementById("entry_0").value == "")
  {
   $("#error").show('slow');
  }
  
  if(document.getElementById("entry_1").value == "")
  {
   $("#error").show('slow');
  }
 }`

Imagine, If I have 20 textboxes. That's why Im trying to call the input:text object itself or the 'form input' to call all textboxes in just one function. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @undefined! Thanks a lot! It worked actually, tried your update! Many thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can not use `value` with jquery object use `val()` function, But this will check only the first textbox returned by the selector.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/kz6FR/1/)**

```
function checking() {    
  var textBox = $('input:text').val();
  if (textBox == "") {
      $("#error").show('slow');
   }
}
```

You can attach `blur` event and do this validation on `losing focus from each textbox.`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/kz6FR/2/)**

```
$('input:text').blur(function() {    
    var textBox = $('input:text').val();
    if (textBox == "") {
        $("#error").show('slow');
    }
});
```

Validation on `submit button` click according to discussion with OP

​**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/kz6FR/3/)**

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function() { 
     $("#error").hide();    
     $('input:text').each(function(){
       if( $(this).val().length == 0)
          $("#error").show('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply, actually I have tried it as well but no good. I have 6 textboxes and two of these textboxes do have values, does it affect the condition? What Im trying to do is once user click the submit button and any of the remaining textboxes is empty the error warning will show.

Comment: Update my answer, I hope  it will help you to do what you want.

Comment: @Adil This is an excellent and very informative answer. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
var textBox = $('input:text').val();

if (textBox==""){ 
  $("#error").show('slow'); 
}
```