# empty jQuery string not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, conditional-statements

Can someone please explain this to me? I am attempting to do something if `key != ''`

```
var key = "";
if($('div[title="Keyword"]').text() != '') {
  key = $('div[title="Keyword"]').text().trim(); 
}

//this always alerts
if (key != '') { alert(key); } 

//this never alerts
if (!key) { alert(key); }
```

Comment: alert the value of key before the if and see what is it equal to. If it's not an empty string, then the first `if` will pass.

Comment: what does `console.log(key)` say?

Comment: I set up a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/SPJPq/ and works as I would expect.  Can you reproduce the issue you are seeing there?

Comment: can you also give you associated HTML code please

Comment: You may have some invisible special character not removed by `trim`

Comment: I don't understand what's asked here. For any non-empty string in `key`, `key != ''` will evaluate to `true`, and `!key` will evaluate to `false`.

Comment: How to check input for empty: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854556/check-if-inputs-are-empty-using-jquery

Comment: @wroniasty `console.log(key)` says it is empty no matter where I put it.

Comment: @raina77ow Isnt `!key` similar to saying `key != '' || key == undefined`

Comment: @Feature: You should log `key.length`. If it comes up as greater than 1, then log `key.charCodeAt(0)`.

Comment: What's actually in the DIV that you're checking? Show us the HTML.

Comment: @Feature Of course not. `!key` will evaluate to `true` only if `key` is falsy; the only falsy String value is `''` - an empty string.

Comment: @user1689607 Good call. `key.length` is 1, `key.charCodeAt(0)` is 8203. I think I can solve this by checking if `key.length > 1`

Comment: @Feature: You should solve it by deleting these characters from your markup. They shouldn't be there. Sometimes they can crop up when you copy and paste code from websites.

Comment: How come checking `key.length > 0` (actually; not 1) is better than checking `key !== ''`, is beyond me.

Comment: @bfavaretto had it right a long time ago. He should add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I said in the comments it might be an invisible character not stripped by `trim`. Well, after your further comments, it's clear that's the case. It's the [U+200B Zero-width space character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm). It probably came from jsfiddle (I'm betting you pasted something from there).