# cant check if the value of input field is empty in jquery

Tags: jquery, variables

```
var costp;
var anzahl_der_personen = $('#anzahl_der_personen').val();

    if( +anzahl_der_personen == 1 ) {
        costp = 0;
    }elseif( $.trim('#anzahl_der_personen').val() === null ){
        costp = 0;
    }else {
         costp = (59 * $('#anzahl_der_personen').val()) - 59;
    }
```

for some reason it never comes to the elseif statement! I tried other ways is .lenght, .is(empty).. to see if the text field is empty but it always goes to the else statment! if the value is not 1 it goes to the else statment. What is the proper way to check if the value is empty or null, because if a user doesnt put anything in to the field I want the variable costp to be 0;

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if inputs are empty using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854556/check-if-inputs-are-empty-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a space between `else if`

Also check for **empty string** rather than **null value**

There is a syntax error in the way you are using the `$.trim` method . It expects a string.

```
   else if( $.trim(anzahl_der_personen) === '' ){
```

Comment: thank you @Sushanth this solved the problem ;) I am going to accept your answer in the next 8 minutes

Comment: @TooCooL .. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript does not have an `elseif` statement. Use `else if` instead.

Also, you're using `$.trim` wrong.

---

Finally, there's no need for all that redundant code. Try this:

```
var costp;
var anzahl_der_personen = +$('#anzahl_der_personen').val();

if ( ! anzahl_der_personen || anzahl_der_personen === 1 ) {
    costp = 0;
} else {
    costp = (59 * anzahl_der_personen) - 59;
}
```