# Check if inputs are empty using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm creating a simple form with validation, and want any empty input or textarea to have a class added, but I do not know how to check for empty inputs.

Currently, it adds to all inputs; I just want the **empty** inputs/textareas. Can anyone help?

HTML:

```
<form id="contactform">
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="name" autofocus >
    <input placeholder="email" >
    <textarea placeholder="message" ></textarea>
    <input type="submit">
    </input>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $("#contactform").submit(function () {
        if($("input, textarea").val() === ""){
        $("input").addClass("error");   
        return false;
        }
        $("input").removeClass("error");
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you think `.val()` would return `0` for empty inputs? [**Read the API documentation.**](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: if the val = 0, it means the input is null?

Comment: @MattBall, JavaScript truthiness strikes again!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if inputs are empty using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854556/check-if-inputs-are-empty-using-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $("#contactform").submit(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(":input").not("[type=submit]").removeClass('error').each(function () {
         if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0) $(this).addClass('error');
     });
 });
```

**[jFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/L9qkZ/)**

(note the preventDefault is there so the form doesn't submit and you can see it work)

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` doesn't return a number, it returns a string. So change `$("input, textarea").val() == 0` to `$("input, textarea").val() === ""`

**EDIT**

as per comments, and to be a bit more comprehensive in your testing for an empty field then

```
$("input, textarea").each(function(){
    var self = $(this),
        thisVal = self.val();
    if($.trim(thisVal) === "" || thisVal.length === 0)
    {
        self.addClass("error");
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd swap the equals with a `trim()` plus a `length` test. Seems to result in the fewest complaints from web users in my own experience.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to submit the form afterwards (adopting the accepted answer). Try this:

```
$("#submit_form").click(function () {
$submit = "yes";
$(":input").not("[type=button]").removeClass('error').each(function () {
    if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0) {
        $(this).addClass('error');
        $submit = "no";
    }
});
if ($submit == "yes") {
    $("#contactform").submit();
}
});
```

This will go through each one and verify it has content and if it doesn't it wont allow you to submit the form. Otherwise the form will submit. I also changed your submit button to be a button instead. It went from:

```
 <input type="submit">
```

To submit with a button:

```
 <input type="button" id="submit_form" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want! but it does it individually, how do I make it do them all at the same time?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? How you have it set up you'd want to apply the error class to the input that is missing.

Comment: I know you accepted an answer but you could also flag a variable when you return false and then add a <div> and apply a message in the <div> saying that all the fields aren't filled out and then you wouldn't have to highlight the specific input fields if that is really what you were looking for.

Comment: I appreciate your interest, but I found my answer. If you still want to help, you can explain why it wont submit when the inputs are filled? http://jsfiddle.net/9F9XH/

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid custom validation for mandatory fields, use https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.js. Add this library in blade (at the beginning of the javascript section). Using this library, if the required fields are not filled, a pop up will appear on submitting form. Validation will work for all "required"  datatypes. For reference: https://jqueryvalidation.org/. This method worked for me.