# value-attribute seems not to show input-field-content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use jquery to check if every input-field has already been filled out. And if yes, I'd like to make a green border around the form.

This was my approach:

```
if($('input:text[value=""], textarea[value=""]').length == 0){
    alert("DONE");
}
```

Hovever the value="" -Selector doesn't work.

It seems that the value-attribute only contains the input-field's default-value, but not the actual content inserted by the user - according to firebug.

This command alerts me the actual contents:

```
$('input:text[value!=""]').each(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

My Question: Where are the actual input-field contents stored? And how can I use jQuery to check efficiently, if there are empty fields?

Comment: Have you considered using jQuery Validate? It can be found [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/validate/)

Comment: you might want something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854556/check-if-inputs-are-empty-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the *attribute* selectors only work with the value the attribute really has. Later on, changing the value of the input will only change the DOM element's internal state.

> Where are the actual input-field contents stored?

You can access the value via the `value` property of the DOM element `elementNode.value`.

> And how can I use jQuery to check efficiently, if there are empty fields?

You can use [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$('input').filter(function() {
    return !this.value;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A neat way of validating inputs is to attach a validation rule to the element for your script to find and validate against.

To make a field required:

`<input type="text" data-validate="required" />`

Your script:

```
$('[data-validate]').each(function() {
    var rule = $(this).attr('data-validate'), value = $(this).val();

    switch (rule) {
        case 'required':
            if (!value) {
                alert('Field invalid!');
            }
        break;
    }
});
```

It works pretty well for me.

You can make it more efficient by selecting only specific element types or children of a specific element (such as a form).

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `.filter()` like this:

```
var empty = $('input:text').filter(function(){ return $(this).val() == "" }).length;

if(empty > 0){
    alert("There are "+empty+" fields which have not been filled out");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my approach if you are not willing to use Jquery validate.

give a class to each of your input fields and then use `Jquery class selector` to test if those all have filled or not. You can use this even for dropdown too.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this construction:

```
var incomplete = $('form :input').filter(function() {
  return $(this).val() == '';
});

if (incomplete) {
  alert('Please fill all fields!');
}
```

**:input** selector selects all input, textarea, select and button elements.

Read this: http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/