# How to validate null value in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to show an error message but want to format the fields depending upon condition below

error message is

```
 ("Record is already present for no"+ $('#Number').val() + " emp1"+ $('#emp1').val() +" emp2"+ $('#emp2').val() +" out date "+ $('#outdate').val() + " indate "+ $('#indate').val());
```

output is :

```
Record is already present for no 123 emp1 AAA emp2 BBB out date 2MAY indate 5MAY
```

now if i'm not passing `emp2` name in the `textbox` 
so value is `null` for `emp2` how can i remove `emp2` also from my above message ?

I tried with `$('#emp2')==null` but at the time of showing how can I delete emp2 which i have taken it into string or how can i reformat my error message ?

Comment: have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854556/check-if-inputs-are-empty-using-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the *ternary operator*:

```
"Record is already present for no "+ $('#Number').val() + ($('#emp1').val() === null ? "" : " emp1"+ $('#emp1').val()) + ($('#emp2').val() === null ? "" : " emp2"+ $('#emp2').val()) +" out date "+ $('#outdate').val() + " indate "+ $('#indate').val());
```

Answer (score 1):

try like..

```
var text = "Record is already present for no";

if($('#Number').val()!=null)// check if null or '' comes
{
 text = text + "$('#Number').val()"
}

if($('#emp1').val()!=null)// check if null or '' comes
{
 text = text + "emp1" +"$('#emp1').val()"
}
```

and so on..

Answer (score 0):

To check a Jquery Object is refered to any objects or not, I usually use .length.

```
if ($('#number').length == 0) {
   // no value
}
```

To check a object is null or undefined, use typeof

```
if (typeof testObject == 'undefined' || testObject == null) {
    // no value
}
```