# How can I use jQuery to check all inputs for blanks?

Tags: jquery, validation, input

I am trying to use JQuery to check whether *all* inputs in a form have been filled. The viewer clicks a button and if the inputs have been filled, cool stuff happens. But if one of the fields hasn't been filled the viewer needs to get a custom warning message. I think I've almost got it but I need some help.

```
$(function() {
$("#btn_click").click(function() {
    if( $("input").val() == 0 ) {
    $("form").append('<span class=".warning">You didn\'t fill out all the fields!</span>');
}
    else {
        //Some cool stuff happens
    }
});
```

});

When I don't fill in any of the inputs, I get the expected behavior with the warning. That's good. However, the "cool stuff" runs if I fill in the first input and leave all the others blank. That's bad. I want the warning to show if *any* of the inputs are left blank. How can I make JQuery test all of the inputs?

Comment: use `.each()` method.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854556/check-if-inputs-are-empty-using-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check it using:

```
if ($("input").length != $('input').filter(function () {
        return $.trim(this.value)
    }).length) {
    /* not all inputs filled */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
$("#btn_click").on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("input").each(function(){
        if(!$(this).val()){
           //error message
            return false;
        }else{
           //remaining code
       }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This almost works but now when I type something in the first input, leave the others blank and click the button, the error message fires AND the remaining code fires. I tried giving all the inputs on this specific form a class in HTML and doing $('.required'), same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can add ID to each input element and then Using Jquery check if any one is blank then show
error message otherwise do your cool stuff

Comment: I would do this except I'm writing the script to act on whichever html document happens to be live on the site. The number of input elements changes depending on which HTML document is live, so I really need to somehow be able to check whichever input elements happen to be there.

Answer (score 0):

`$('input').val()` will only retrieve the value of the first input. If you want to check all the input, you should check all input with `each` (just an example, you can use others stuff) :

```
$('btn_click').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(e) ;
    var allOk = true ;
    $('input').each(function () { // Iterate over input
        if (!$('input').val()) { // Don't check against 0
            allOk = false ; // If the input isn't ok
        }
    }) ;
    if (!allOk) {
        // Warning message
    }
    else {
        // Some cool stuff
    }
}) ;
```

Comment: I tried this code and it behaves the same way as the code I started the post with. It seems to only test the first input. When I fill the first input, leave the others blank and click the button, the "cool stuff" still happens.

Answer (score 0):

try `$("input").filter(function(){return this.value==''}).length > 0`

or bettter, as you already are using jQuery use some sophisticated validation plugin