# How To Check All Input Fields In A Form To See If They Are Empty?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How would I check all the input fields in a form (check box, text and radio) to see if they are empty. Then highlight the empty ones with a red border. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if inputs are empty using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854556/check-if-inputs-are-empty-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you could do something like this:

```
(function($) {

// After check for form submission
$('form :input').each(function(i) {
    if( $(this).val() == '' ) {
        // Just remove the closest() method if you want to give the 
        // actual input a border
        $(this).closest('.parent-div').css({ 'border': '1px solid #c20000' });
    }
});

})(jQuery);
```