# checking if text field is empty via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have the following Code

```js
$('#myform').submit(function() {
  return false;
});

$('#insert').click(function() {
  var value = $.trim($("#msg").val());
  if (value.length < 0) {
    alert("לא הכנסת הודעה !");
  } else {
    $.post(
      $('#myform').attr('action'),
      $('#myform :input').serializeArray(),
      function(result) {
        document.getElementById('msg').value = "";
        $('#result').html(result);
      }
    );
  }
});
```

```html
<form method="post" action="insertmsg.php" id="myform">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td width="100%">
        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="ההודעה שלך" name="msg" id="msg"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button id='insert' class="form-control">שלח</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <p id='result'></p>
</form>
```

I'm unable to check if the field is empty or not. I tried something but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if inputs are empty using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854556/check-if-inputs-are-empty-using-jquery)

Comment: Some sensible indentation would help the readability of your code.

Comment: I can't see any if statements.

Comment: _"i tried something"_ - Show us that part.

Comment: **Edit your question**... Dumping code in comment is event worst than bad indentation.

Comment: sorry , i edited my post haha

Comment: @Jeniapus Your can edit your question to update the code and please read the FAQ how to format code in a question, it's the advanced help link when you click the ? symbol on the editor. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: `if (value.length < 0) {` It cannot be less than zero. `if (value.length == 0) {` is what you should use.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Get the value of the `textarea` and check to see if there is a value. You can also use `required="required"` if you want to use the browser check.

```
<textarea class="form-control" placeholder="ההודעה שלך" name="msg" id="msg" required="required"></textarea>

$('#insert').click(function () {
        var textField = $('#myform').find('textarea#msg'); // Or give textarea an id and find that. 
        var textFieldValue = textField.val();
        if (textFieldValue.trim() == '') return;

        $.post(
            $('#myform').attr('action'),
            $('#myform:input').serializeArray(),
            function (result) {
                document.getElementById('msg').value = ""; // this part only clears the textarea after submission .
                $('#result').html(result);
            }
        );

    });
```

Comment: No problem! Be sure to mark the answer correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if ($(textarae #msg).val() == '' || $(textarae #msg).val() == null)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.