# How can I check if all required fields are selected before hiding a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
var cnt = 2;
$('.next').click(function() {
  var reqField = true;
  $(this).siblings('table').find('tbody tr:nth-child(' + cnt + ') td').each(function() {
    var ele = $(this).find('center').find('select');
    if ((!$(ele).attr('disabled')) && $(ele).val() === '') {
      reqField = false;
    }
  });

  if (reqField) {
    $(this).parent().hide().next().show();
    cnt = cnt + 2;
  }
});

$('select').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'MSA')
    $(this).closest('td').next().find('select').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="main">
  <form action="ServletExample" method="post">
    <div id="div1">
      <table id="t01" border="2">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Welcome1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width=15%>
              <center><select id="L1" required>
                           <option value="">Selection1</option>
                           <option value="MSA">MSA</option>
                           <option value="dialect">Dialect</option>         
                        </select></center>
            </td>
            <td width=12%>
              <center><select id="D1" required>
                           <option value="">Selection2</option>
                           <option value="EGY">EGY</option>
                           <option value="GLF">GLF</option>
                        </select></center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck1" value="sentence" /> sentence1<br>
              <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck2" value=" words" />words1
              <textarea name="T" id="myText13" rows="3" cols="50"></textarea>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Welcome2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width=15%>
              <center><select id="L2" required>
                           <option value="">Selection1</option>
                           <option value="MSA">MSA</option>
                           <option value="dialect">Dialect</option>         
                        </select></center>
            </td>
            <td width=12%>
              <center><select id="D2" required>
                           <option value="">Selection2</option>
                           <option value="EGY">EGY</option>
                           <option value="GLF">GLF</option>
                        </select></center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck3" value="sentence" /> sentence2<br>
              <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck4" value=" words" />words2
              <textarea name="T" id="myText13" rows="3" cols="50"></textarea>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <hr />
      <button class="next">NEXT</button>
    </div>

    <div id="div2" style="display:none">
      <table id="t01" border="2">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Welcome3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <center><select id="L3" required>
                           <option value="">Selection3</option>
                           <option value="MSA">MSA</option>
                           <option value="dialect">Dialect</option>
                        </select></center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center><select id="D3" required>
                           <option value="">Selection4</option>
                           <option value="EGY">EGY</option>
                           <option value="GLF">GLF</option>
                        </select></center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck5" value="sentence" /> sentence3<br>
              <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck6" value=" words" />words3
              <textarea name="T" id="myText13" rows="3" cols="50"></textarea>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <hr />
      <button class="next">NEXT</button>
    </div>

    <div id="div3" style="display:none">
      <table id="t01" border="2">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Welcome4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <center><select id="L4" required>
                           <option value="">Selection5</option>
                           <option value="MSA">MSA</option>
                           <option value="dialect">Dialect</option>
                        </select></center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center><select id="D4" required>
                           <option value="">Selection6</option>
                           <option value="EGY">EGY</option>
                           <option value="GLF">GLF</option>
                        </select></center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck7" value="sentence" /> sentence4<br>
              <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck8" value=" words" />words4
              <textarea name="T" id="myText13" rows="3" cols="50"></textarea>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button onclick="submit">Send</button>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

I want to hide a div and show another div. I used jQuery and the hide step is fine:

```
<body>

 <div id="div1">
  <select id="L1" required>
        <option value="0">please select</option>
        <option value="A">A</option> 
        <option value="B">B</option> 
  </select>
  <select id="C1" required>
        <option value="0">please select</option>
        <option value="C">C</option> 
        <option value="D">D</option> 
  </select>
  <select id="D1" required>
        <option value="0">please select</option>
        <option value="E">E</option> 
        <option value="F">F</option> 
  </select>
  <button class="next">next</button>
 </div>
 <div id="div2" style="display:none">
  <select id="D2" required>
        <option value="0">please select</option>
        <option value="3">3</option> 
        <option value="4">4</option> 
  </select>
  <button class="next">next</button>
 </div>
 <script>
    $('.next').click(function(){   
       $(this).parent().hide().next().show(); //hide parent and show next  
    });
 </script>
</body>
```

But the problem is that the div can hide even if some required fields are not selected.

I have 5 dropdown select options in each div and users must select an option for each dropdown before the div is hidden, so if the **Next** button in the first div is clicked, it must check that all the required fields are selected, and then hide the first div and show the second div.

How I can check this?

I got the problem, it is in the column tag , because I designed the webpage as a table and put every select options in a column.

```
<td><select id="C1" required>
       <option value="0">please select</option>
       <option value="C">C</option> 
       <option value="D">D</option> 
</select></td>
```

so, how I can check the select inside a td tag. **Below is the structure of HTML**

```
<html>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <form action="ServletExample" method="post">
      <div id="div1">
        <table id="t01" border="2">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center><select id="L1" required>
                               <option value="">Selection1</option>
                               <option value="MSA">MSA</option>
                               <option value="dialect">Dialect</option>         
                            </select></center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center><select id="D1" required>
                               <option value="">Selection2</option>
                               <option value="EGY">EGY</option>
                               <option value="GLF">GLF</option>
                            </select></center>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <hr />
        <button class="next">NEXT</button>
      </div>

      <div id="div2" style="display:none">
        <table id="t01" border="2">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center><select id="L2" required>
                               <option value="">Selection1</option>
                               <option value="MSA">MSA</option>
                               <option value="dialect">Dialect</option>
                            </select></center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center><select id="D2" required>
                               <option value="">Selection2</option>
                               <option value="EGY">EGY</option>
                               <option value="GLF">GLF</option>
                            </select></center>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <hr />
        <button class="next">NEXT</button>
      </div>

      <div id="div3" style="display:none">
        <table id="t01" border="2">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center><select id="L3" required>
                               <option value="">Selection1</option>
                               <option value="MSA">MSA</option>
                               <option value="dialect">Dialect</option>
                            </select></center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center><select id="D3" required>
                               <option value="">Selection2</option>
                               <option value="EGY">EGY</option>
                               <option value="GLF">GLF</option>
                            </select></center>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <button onclick="submit">Send</button>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if inputs are empty using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854556/check-if-inputs-are-empty-using-jquery)

Comment: What `div`? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: You need a validator function. What have you tried so far?

Comment: How I can use a validator function?

Comment: @Areej see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/bo5fdvLv/

```js
$('.next').click(function() {
  var reqField = true;
  $(this).siblings('select').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === '0') {
      reqField = false;
    }
  });

  if (reqField) {
    $(this).closest('div').hide().siblings('div').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <select id="L1" required>
        <option value="0">please select</option>
        <option value="A">A</option> 
        <option value="B">B</option> 
  </select>
  <select id="C1" required>
        <option value="0">please select</option>
        <option value="C">C</option> 
        <option value="D">D</option> 
  </select>
  <select id="D1" required>
        <option value="0">please select</option>
        <option value="E">E</option> 
        <option value="F">F</option> 
  </select>
  <button class="next">next</button>
</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none">
  <select id="D2" required>
        <option value="0">please select</option>
        <option value="3">3</option> 
        <option value="4">4</option> 
  </select>
  <button class="next">next</button>
</div>
```

You can change the below code of mine 
`$(this).closest('div').hide().siblings('div').show();` to `$(this).parent().hide().next().show();`

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work in my code, it shows the second div even if no option is selected. I don't why:(

Comment: @Areej.. I didn't got the same situation. Can you elaborate the situation??? More over it's your code, I just added jQuery code to it..

Comment: I tried the code in a small html file it works perfect but when added it to my whole code in .jsp file it does't work. This the page which I tried to create. alshutayri.com/index_1.jsp

Comment: No error but when I clicked next button the second div shown while no any of required select option was selected.

Comment: I got the problem, see my question please.

Comment: I added the HTML structure to the question, please have a look on it.

Comment: Thank you so much, but what if I have 5 rows in every div?

Comment: I got it thank you, I checked 5 rows but still one small thing that when the user select MSA option in selection 1, I need to disable the second selection 2, I did the onchange function to disable selection 2 but the problem now when the selection 2 is disabled the second div doesn't show because the condition is false.

Comment: @Areej.. Here you go with an updated solution https://jsfiddle.net/bo5fdvLv/2/ . Please update the question accordingly.

Comment: @ Shiladitya.. Thank you for your cooperation and keep trying to help me I added the snippet to the question, I don't know what I could say but still it is not working just checking some select fields and accept empty selection. :(

Comment: @ Shiladitya **Perfect**, **Thank you**, that's what I want, it working now.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a validate function to check if the `select` element has a value selected.  Below is a working example with validation. It checks to see if the user has selected a value; if they have, it advances to the next `select` element, otherwise it does not.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

 <div id="div1">
  <h4>D1</h4>
  <select id="D1" required>
        <option value="0">please select</option>
        <option value="1">1</option> 
        <option value="2">2</option> 
  </select>
  <button class="next">next</button>
 </div>
 <div id="div2" style="display:none">
  <h4>D2</h4>
  <select id="D2" required>
        <option value="0">please select</option>
        <option value="3">3</option> 
        <option value="4">4</option> 
  </select>
  <button class="next">next</button>
 </div>
 <script>
    $('.next').click(function(){
       if (validated(this)) {  // call the validate function
         if (!!this.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.id) {  // check to make sure there is another element to switch to
          $(this).parent().hide().next().show(); //hide parent and show next
         }
       }
    });
    function validated(btn) {
      // check if a value has been selected
      var el = btn.previousSibling.previousSibling;
      if (el.value !== "0") { return true; }  // a value has been selected
      else { return false; }  // no value has been selected
    }
 </script>
</body>
```

I also added a check to not advance to the next item if it is the last `select` element.  You can take that `if` check out if you don't require it.  (I added the `h4` element just to show which `div` is currently active.)

Comment: Thank you so much, it works in this small example but when I added to my code it doesn't work :(

Comment: Can you append your question to add the rest of your code? Something in your code is preventing it from working. Are you getting an error in the console?

Comment: No any error in the console, the code is too long but I will try to add part of it.

Comment: I got the problem, see my question please.