# Jquery addClass() on a input field not working

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following css:

```
.error .form-inline{ border-color: #a94442; -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075); box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075); }
```

and the following function:

```
function myFunction() {
   if (year_value == "" && monthDay_value == "" && char_value == "" && rest_value == ""){ 
            alert("ERROR");
            $(':text').addClass("error");
            document.getElementById("AuthStatus").focus();
   }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is when the user enters wrong data in the input fields, to highlight the input where the user input the wrong info. However, the `addClass()` appears to not work correctly. I also change the css to target the input fields as well but it doesnt work either:

```
.error input[type="text"]{ border-color: #a94442; -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075); box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075); }
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the form:

```
            <div class="override_panel-body mobileAdjustments">
            <form class="form-inline" id="AuthStatus">
                <div class="background-color form-group">
                    <div class="padding1"><h3 class="fontWeight">Stay Informed</h3></div>
                        <p style="padding-left:6px !important;">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei ubique disputando mea, sit in duis aliquip vivendo. Cum at justo facilisis. His ad nisl reprimique, eos no liber suscipit. Ex sed viderer phaedrum.
                        </p>
                        <div class="input-group panel-body" style="padding-left:6px !important;">
                            <input id="year" type="text" class="" placeholder="XXXX" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" />
                            <input id="monthDay" type="text" class="" placeholder="XXXX" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" />
                            <input id="char" type="text" class="" placeholder="XXXX" aria-describedby="basic-addon3" />
                            <input id="rest" type="text" class="" placeholder="XXXX" aria-describedby="basic-addon4" />
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input id ="auth"  class="override_btn btn-info btn-block adjustments" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction()" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input id="clear" class="btn btn-light clear" onclick="ClearForm()" type="button" value="Clear" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="pddingBottom" style="padding-left:6px !important;">
                            Don't have an authorization number? Contact your doctor to get a copy.
                        </p>
                </div>
                <h3 class="fontWeight">FAQ</h3>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei ubique disputando mea, sit in duis aliquip vivendo. Cum at justo facilisis. His ad nisl reprimique, eos no liber suscipit. Ex sed viderer phaedrum.
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **HTML5:**

```
<input id="year" type="text" class="" placeholder="XXXX" required>
```

You can check with **Jquery** in another way:

```
<input id="year" type="text" placeholder="XXXX">
<script>
$('#year').on('blur',function(){
if($('#year').val()==''){ 
    $('#year').addClass('yourClassName');
}else{
    $('#year').removeClass('yourClassName');
});
</script>
```

If you need a simple validate function, use HTML5. And remember to validate in the backend as well.

**UPDATE1**

I just checked your submit button with "onclick" event. Please, use events  outside HTML, it will keep it more organized and with better performance.

**UPDATE2 and 3**
A better answer:

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('#AuthStatus').on('submit'){
    var errors = 0;
    $("#AuthStatus :input").map(function(){
         if( !$(this).val() ) {
              $(this).addClass('warning');
              errors++;
        } else if ($(this).val()) {
              $(this).removeClass('warning');
        }   
    });
    if(errors > 0){
        $('#errorwarn').text("All fields are required");
        return false;
    }
}
```

});

Not tested. Note: remove the "onclick" on submit button. Full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6781531/7259765).

Comment: @ Marcelo Agimovel: I am not able to use HTML5 do to the clients I work for are using a older version of IE :/.

Comment: @RobertoFlores you can use the second option, and actually improve it to avoid several codes to do the same thing.

Comment: @ Marcelo: I have tired that approach as well and it still not working. Not sure what is going on. I added it in my function and out of my function

Comment: @ Marcelo: Still not working. Not sure what the "td" is for, but I assume for a table so replace that with input. Yeah, this approach is not valid, at least for me

Comment: Ill updat one last time, but's all about you adapt the code.

Comment: @ Marcelo: I did. Thats the frustrating part

Answer (score 0):

The CSS selector (although actually you shouldn't need this) should be

```
input[type="text"].error  { ... }`
```

(the `error` class is applied to the `input` element),

and the jQuery selector should be

```
$('input[type=text]').addClass("error");
```

Comment: @ Johannes: I have tried your approach as well and it still not working. I know I can do it with the DOM but it isnt the same styling

Comment: @RobertoFlores You should not downvote this answer. It's correct. There are other errors in your code, like the undefined variables in the conditional of your function.

Comment: @AyexeM: I didnt down vote this answer and those are defined. Do apologize for not adding all of my code. I thought it would be better to just put what was needed.